# Machine code to ARM7 Assembly

Tags: assembly, disassembly, machine-code, arm7

I'm trying to get the following machine code instruction written in ARMv7 Assembly

```
1010 1110 00001011 0000 0000 0000 0100
```

I wrote it out in hex as below

```
0xAE0B0004
```

After messing about with several different instructions with ARMSim, I finally got down to:

`andge  r0,r11,#4`

However this produces the hex machine code

```
0xA20B0004
```

I'm still getting the second nibble incorrectly, I tried to use the Coprocessor instruction but I'm unsure why ARMSim is not recognizing the command. Here is my CDP command:

`cdpge 0,and,r0,r11,#4,#0`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I created this file named aa.S:

```
    .globl test
test:
    .text
    .word 0xAE0B0004
```

Assembled it by arm-none-eabi-gcc -c aa.S -o aa.o.
Then did arm-none-eabi-objdump -d aa.o and got this:

> 00000000 test:
>
> 0:    ae0b0004    cdpge   0, 0, cr0, cr11, cr4, {0}